# Header flickers when StackNavigator is inside BottomTabNavigator with headerShown=false on Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is a snack showing the issue: https://snack.expo.dev/@piotrpcpl/nested-navigator-header-flicker . From what I tested it must be run on physical device to observe the behavior.

I have a bottom tab navigator from React Navigation 6. Inside each tab there is a stack navigator. I want to only display headers of Stack Navigators so I set Tab Navigator's option `headerShown` to false for each tab (on the demo snack it's only set for second tab to show the difference - there is no flicker if both headers are shown).

This causes a flicker of the header when first opening of the tab (on Android only). In the snack I set `unmountOnBlur` to better display the issue, so it happens on every tab opening instead of just first one. It looks like the header of tab navigator is briefly rendered or the space for it is reserved and immediately later it's removed, but it's very noticeable and looks broken. It works ok on iOS.

Is there a way to prevent the flicker? Is it a bug in React Navigation?

Full source code of the example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


function Screen1() {
  return (
    <View></View>
  )
}

function Screen2() {
  return (
    <View></View>
  )
}

const Stack1Navigation = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Stack2Navigation = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Stack1Navigator() {
  return (
    <Stack1Navigation.Navigator>
      <Stack1Navigation.Screen name="Screen 1" component={Screen1} />
    </Stack1Navigation.Navigator>
  )
}

function Stack2Navigator() {
  return (
    <Stack2Navigation.Navigator>
      <Stack2Navigation.Screen name="Screen 2" component={Screen2} />
    </Stack2Navigation.Navigator>
  )
}

const BottomNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomNavigator() {
  return  (
    <BottomNavigation.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        unmountOnBlur: true
      }}>
      <BottomNavigation.Screen
        name="Screen 1"
        component={Stack1Navigator}>
      </BottomNavigation.Screen>
      <BottomNavigation.Screen
        name="Screen 2"
        component={Stack2Navigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}>
      </BottomNavigation.Screen>
    </BottomNavigation.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <BottomNavigator></BottomNavigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you facing this issue in android only?

Comment: Yes, Android only. Also it looks ok when using Android tab in this snack. But when I used "use my device" and tried it on 3 different brands of Android phones it's flickering on all of them.

Comment: it's working fine in my android device.

Comment: What Android version do you have? I have this behavior on a Samsung with Android 12, and on Honor with 10.

Comment: Oneplus Android 11

Comment: https://blog.deversity.com/2021/10/combining-drawer-tab-and-stack_15.html

Comment: check this one it may help you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue for now by getting rid of `NativeStackNavigator` and switching to `StackNavigator`.

Looks like `NativeStackNavigator` is currently broken.

Answer (score 0):

As Episodex mentions, use NativeStackNavigator.

Then use headerMode:'none' inside the navigator that should not have the header.

If the project structure is as follows
-- stacknavigator (call it A)
---- tabnavigator
---- stacknavigator (call it B)

A should look like:

```
// your stack navigator
const App = StackNavigator(
{...},
  { headerMode: 'screen' }
)
```

B should look like:

```
const CustomerManagerStack = StackNavigator(
  {... },
  { headerMode: 'none' }
)
```

Source:
[Discussion on github about StackNavigator inside StackNavigator produces two headers](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/614#issuecomment-289410296)

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem. For now, I have added it.